# how to refresh page in jquery and clear cache

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, caching

I need to reload page after progress bar finish job and clear cache, but I'can not refresh it from php, because header sent before reached redirecting section.

After finish php function the page will be reload with jQuery.

At the first time of page entrance function work fine and the progress bar work to but after finish function and reload page the progress bar it's not working even with *ctrl + F5* ,but when I go to another page and come back is work fine, so I guess the problem is with  page redirecting/Reloading.

I use custom progress bar according to intercooler.js and use progress bar function like this:

```
    // progress bar counter
    function progress_go(from, to) {

        var bar = new ProgressBar.Path('#cloud-path', {
            //easing: 'easeInOut',
            duration: 500,
            step: function (state, path) {
                var value = Math.round(path.value() * 100);

                if (value == 99) {
                    window.location.assign("/machine/?id=<?php echo $data['machine']['detail']['id'] ?>");
                }

                if (value === 0) {
                    $("#cloud-progress").find(".counter > span").html('0')
                } else {
                    $("#cloud-progress").find(".counter > span").html(value)
                }
            }
        });

        bar.set(from / 100);
        bar.animate(to / 100);  // Number from 0.0 to 1.0
    }
```

this function counter character that send from php [flush] and at the end reload page. I use windwos.location.reload(true); but it's not work neither.

It's just seem the page is not reloading well and keep data in cache.

I try to clear cache in php with this code:

```
// set php execution time to unlimited
set_time_limit(0);

// disable cache on server
@ini_set('zlib.output_compression', 0);
@ini_set('output_buffering', 0);
@ini_set('implicit_flush', 1);


// set content length to calculate progress percentage
header("Content-length: 101");

@ob_end_clean();
```

> Please don't give me negative mark because I'm really tired with this
>   code maybe I said somethings wrong.If you need more info just tell me and I give you.

Comment: **I find some new issue, after reloading page the function that contains progress bar be come undefined.**